# Async Service Call needs to pause

Tags: android, android-service

I hope this isn't too much jibberish. I have implemented an Async web service call because I didn't want the phone / app / ui to lock up while waiting for data....however I do not want the program to continue executing which is what it is now doing and crashing.

My app request data from the service and the service returns an xml doc. While the service is generating the doc my program continues to execute and crashes when it gets to the section where the code is looking for the file...that isn't there yet.

So I need to know how / what does a person do in java for this scenario? In C# I'd know what to do. Here is the code for the async call and feel free to point out anything wrong with it as well.

```
public class DataExchangeServiceClient
{
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.icyarmtesting.com/";

private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) 
{
    client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
}

public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) 
{
      client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
  }

  private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) 
  {
      return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
  }

}
```

and then the implementation...yes I know it is hard coded for now.

```
protected static boolean GetExerciseData() throws JSONException
{
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("Action", "");
    params.put("ProgramID", "8008009");
    params.put("UserName", "joex");
    params.put("Password", "dude!");


    DataExchangeServiceClient.get("liftdataexchange.xamlx", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONArray timeline)
        {
            try
            {
            JSONObject firstEvent = (JSONObject) timeline.get(0);
            String XML_DOC_String = firstEvent.getString("text");
            }
            catch(JSONException jse)
            {

            }
            //send it off to become a document
        }
    });

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions to your problem. But the best one is to use an Android Service. I will explain a bit more your alternatives.

- You could start a new [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)
- You can use an [AyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (more Android)
- You can use a [Loader](http://neilgoodman.net/2011/12/26/modern-techniques-for-implementing-rest-clients-on-android-4-0-and-below-part-1/)
- You can use a [service](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=xHXn3Kg2IQE)

I am the co-author of a library dedicated to this topic : [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice). Here is an [infographics](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/blob/master/gfx/RoboSpice-InfoGraphics.jpg) that explain why using a service is the best approach. That's what we do in RoboSpice and we really believe it's the best way to perform a long runnning background task such as downloading data from the web.

More over RoboSpice provides different modules to help you perform REST requests such as the [Spring Android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) Module, [Google Http Java Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/) module (or [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit), soon to be released).

I encourage you to move toward this library, it will handle a lot of the complexity of background tasking for you.

Comment: Well to be honest with you I looked at Robospice because I started with the Android AsyncTask and was getting numerous errors. Robospice sounded great but I got lost trying to decipher which three libraries I needed. This is all a new world to me and while I'm not afraid to learn I am not yet able to decipher large amount of complex info specific to the java world yet.

Comment: Fine to give us that feedback. We are actually building a new way to help non maven developpers to use RoboSpice : we provide simple samples and you can easily turn them to a standard ADT project using ant. Would you like to try this out ?

Comment: Absolutely. I'm willing to help. If you are looking for a dumb user I'm your man. Honestly I have been a C# .NET developer for 15 years so I'm pretty comfortable with development just learning a new environment (Eclipse) and language (java).

Comment: Can I ask you to try this documentation page on our new samples : https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/wiki/Using-RoboSpice-without-Maven-2. Samples are here now : https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples. Please report any trouble on our discussion group so we can write to each other directly.